# confirmable module error in devise 1.4.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mongoid

I have upgrade to **devise 1.4.9** and I have a problem
with **:confirmable module**.

After confirm user with email that send devise, I try login with the
user confirmed and I get the next message:

**"You have to confirm your account before continuing."**

Some idea?

I using Mongoid and Devise 1.4.9. In devise **Dont Working for me with old version gem in this Project.**

I have **other project** rails with the same devise user model, controller, views, confirmable views, routes and working fine.

But with this project dont working. I dont know that I have doing bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works in Devise 1.4.8, and doesn't in 1.4.9, [report it](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to the Devise team as an issue. It's unlikely we will be able to help any further here.

Comment: Sorry I edited the post. Dont working for me in old version gem. Sorry I checked in devise 1.4.7, 1.4.6, 1.4.5 and 1.4.8 and dont working.